# Question concerning modelling an interaction (two continuous variables) with GAM (package mgcv)

Tags: interaction, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

I have a question concerning modeling an interaction (two continuous variables) with GAM (package mgcv) where I get different results when I include the main effects or not next to the interaction.

I want to run an interaction in gam (mgcv package) between two continuous variables. I have a-priori hypothesis, thus I am mainly interested in the interaction of Density (Dens) and Predators (Pred) on a binomial response variable (0/1) being nest success (Success). I have one additional continuous variables (Dist) to correct for an effect of distance to the sea as well as two random effects (Year and Habitat). 
I found on the internet and in books that I should use the ti-smooth if I understand correctly, however, I am wondering if I should include the main effects alone next to the interaction as described in gam 1 or only the interaction as described in gam 2. I can’t really understand what the difference is between the two models. Is it really comparable with a GLM, where main effects need to be included next to an interaction or is it slightly different? Is there any literature that confirms that using gam 2 (only interaction) is valid and appropriate? As I learned for GLMs, we should always include the main effects as well. 
The results of the two models are quite different. The summary indicates the interaction being significant in gam2 but not in gam1 also the contour plots are different. How worried should I be about the different significance levels between the two models? Concerning the AIC model 1 (main effect+interaction) fits better. I am really doubting which model is correct and could not find any clear solution to my problem on the internet. Maybe there is also something wrong with my code? For my feeling gam 2 better represents the raw data points.

Gam 1 code and it's summary:

```
gam_1 <- gam(Success ~ ti(Dens)+ti(Pred)+ti(Dens, Pred)+
                s(Dist)+s(Year,bs="re")+s(Habitat, bs="re"),method="REML",
              data = data,
              family = binomial)

Family: binomial 
Link function: logit 

Formula:
Success ~ ti(Dens) + ti(Pred) + ti(Dens, Pred) + s(Dist) + s(Year, 
    bs = "re") + s(Habitat, bs = "re")

Parametric coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)   0.3133     0.4422   0.709    0.479

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
                edf Ref.df Chi.sq  p-value    
ti(Dens)      1.522  1.830  1.138  0.55678    
ti(Pred)      2.136  2.484 11.541  0.00454 ** 
ti(Dens,Pred) 4.708  6.142  8.740  0.21795    
s(Dist)       6.973  7.896 35.889 1.56e-05 ***
s(Year)       2.187  8.000  5.373  0.03956 *  
s(Habitat)    3.869  6.000 11.476  0.01440 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-sq.(adj) =  0.262   Deviance explained = 23.2%
-REML = 316.43  Scale est. = 1         n = 553
```

The Gam 2 code and its summary is:

```
gam_2 <- gam(Success ~ ti(Dens, Pred)+
               s(Dist)+s(Year,bs="re") +s(Habitat, bs="re"),method="REML",
             data = data,
             family = binomial)

Family: binomial 
Link function: logit 

Formula:
Success ~ ti(Dens, Pred) + s(Dist) + s(Year, bs = "re") + 
    s(Habitat, bs = "re")

Parametric coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)   0.1738     0.3142   0.553     0.58

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
                edf Ref.df Chi.sq  p-value    
ti(Dens,Pred) 5.378  6.899 15.617   0.0283 *  
s(Dist)       6.989  7.926 33.282 6.23e-05 ***
s(Year)       2.532  8.000  5.599   0.0602 .  
s(Habitat)    3.510  6.000 23.649 3.25e-05 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-sq.(adj) =  0.237   Deviance explained = 20.8%
-REML = 325.09  Scale est. = 1         n = 553
```

The AIC of both models is:

```
            df      AIC
gam_1 27.67462 627.8634
gam_2 24.29912 639.4185
```

The contour plots of both models are:
[image: Contour plots of gam 1 and gam 2]

Comment: The help page of `ti` says that `ti` is only appropriate when the main effects are also present. In the absence of main effects, I think you could use `te(Dens, Pred)`.

Comment: I am also in a same situation that you are but after reading the r help page on gam (http://127.0.0.1:30636/library/mgcv/html/gam.models.html), it is ok only to use the interaction terms but you can read and decide.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/311322)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/311331)